# Good running bag for laptop

Tags: running

I live in a major metropolitan area and I've started running home instead of taking the bus.  That being said, sometimes I need to take my work laptop home with me and - if possible - I would like to not have this be an excuse to not run home.

That being said, are there any good running back packs which will help keep a laptop snug and safe from sweat/water?

Comment: I'd also suggest safe from a fall too. I had a manhole collapse on me while jogging to work last week, one smashed phone, one smashed laptop.

Comment: You can look at [this other question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/running-with-a-backpack) for some ideas, but avoid asking for shopping recommendations. See the [faq].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Incase Compact Backpack](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/H5014ZM/A?fnode=MTY1NDA2Ng&p=4) should be perfect for you needs.  It hugs one's back very well and I do believe it is water resistant.